# Block-scoped declaration let const function class not yet supported outside strict mode in kriasoft react boiler plate

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, ecmascript-6

I am a starter in react and ES6. I started with the boilerplate "https://github.com/kriasoft/react-static-boilerplate"

As mentioned in the docs, i Did npm install->node run. But I am getting an error
as `"Block-scoped declaration(let, const, hunciton, class) not yet supported outside strict mode."`

I tried to put "use strict" at top of the run file, but shows another  error "process.argv.includes is not a function"

I am using node version : 4.3.0, npm : 4.0.2. Does this cause the issue. 
Do the version matter to support the es6 variables or is this any other issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

node v4.x uses an older version of V8 (4.5) which did not fully support all scenarios for block-scoped variable declarations in sloppy (non-strict) mode. If you upgrade to a newer version of node, such as node v6.x, you won't have a problem because of the newer version of V8 used there (5.1).

Similarly, `Array.prototype.includes` was available behind a flag (--harmony_array_includes) in older versions of V8 (including the version used in node v4.x). However, since node v6.x, you can use it without a harmony flag.

For more ECMAScript compatibility information, check http://node.green.